# Bootstrap alert shows up only once in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

When I click the save button on the first time, the alert shows up fine. But every time after that, the alert doesn't show up unless I do a hard refresh.

Here is the JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfX57/953/)

```js
$("#success-alert").hide();
$("#saveChange").click(function showAlert() {
  $("#success-alert").alert();
  $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function() {
    $("#success-alert").alert('close');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
<div class="product-options">
  <button id="saveChange" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-mini">Save</button>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
  <strong>Success! </strong>
  Your changes has saved.
</div>
```

Comment: Can you link the jsFiddle itself?

Comment: @nurdyguy The fact is that the editor removed it, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/mfX57/953/) the link

Comment: I edited it back as well. THANKS for helping the newbie :)

Comment: Try reading the docs. What is opacity 500 supposed to do? Opacity only goes from 0-1 ( would know that also if read the docs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the line

```
$("#success-alert").alert('close');
```

destroys your alert so you cannot open it again.
remove that line and your alert will show each time